# inserting data in oracle from java having problem

Tags: java, oracle

I've centos6.4 in both server and client in VM. I'm trying to store some values (jTextFieldBookID.getText(), jTextFieldBookName.getText(), jTextFieldCategory.getText(), jTextAreaDescription.getText(), and sqdate.) in oracle 11gr2 from java (java SE 8). but having hundreds of errors. I am not getting the solution.

code is:

```
tablebookmaster:-
SQL> desc tablebookmaster;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 BOOKID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 BOOKNAME                           VARCHAR2(45)
 CATEGORY                           VARCHAR2(30)
 DESCRIPTION                        VARCHAR2(60)
 REGISTRYDATE                       DATE
```

ClassConnectDB file:

```
package PackageInventory;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ClassConnectDB 
{


    public static Connection connectdb()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn = null;

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@serverora11gr2:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");


            return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " exception in ClassConnectDB.connectdb() is :  " + e);
            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

file jFrameBookMaster:

```
 import java.sql.*;

//import java.sql.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.text.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.text.DateFormat;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;





 private void jButtonSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

 {                                            

  //Date date =  jDateChooserRegistryDate.getDate();

     try

     {



        //conn = ClassConnectDB.connectdb();



        conn = ClassConnectDB.connectdb();



        String JTextfieldBookIdStr = jTextFieldBookID.getText();

        String JTextFieldBooknameStr = jTextFieldBookName.getText();

        String JTexTFieldCategoryStr = jTextFieldCategory.getText();

        String JtextAeraDesciptionStr = jTextAreaDescription.getText();







        java.util.Date udate = new java.util.Date();

        udate = jXDatePickerRegistryDate.getDate();



        udate = jXDatePickerRegistryDate.getDate();



        java.sql.Date sqdate = new java.sql.Date(udate.getTime());

        //sqdate = new java.sql.Date(udate.getTime());







        String sql = "insert into tablebookmaster values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);



        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(JTextfieldBookIdStr) );

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"

        pst.setString(2,JTextFieldBooknameStr);

        pst.setString(3,JTexTFieldCategoryStr);

        pst.setString(4,JtextAeraDesciptionStr);

        pst.setDate(5, sqdate);

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        int inserted  = pst.executeUpdate();



        if(inserted == 1)

        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"row inserted successfully");       

        }



        else

        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry!. Your record has not saved");

        }



        conn.close();

   }

    catch(Exception e)

    {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exception in jButtonSaveActionPerformed : " + e);



    }

}
```

The error message:

```
Dec 13, 2018 12:26:01 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans    

WARNING: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:313)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:201)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:197)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)

    at PackageInventory.ClassConnectDB.connectdb(ClassConnectDB.java:17)

    at PackageInventory.JFrameBookMaster.jButtonSaveActionPerformed(JFrameBookMaster.java:225)

    at PackageInventory.JFrameBookMaster.access$000(JFrameBookMaster.java:26)

    at PackageInventory.JFrameBookMaster$1.actionPerformed(JFrameBookMaster.java:71)

    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)

    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)

    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)

    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)

    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)

    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)

    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)

    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)

    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)

    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)

    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)

    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.internal is sealed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:394)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)

    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)

    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef.get(ClassRef.java:92)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef$XMLTypeClassRef.<init>(ClassRef.java:120)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef$XMLTypeClassRef.newInstance(ClassRef.java:109)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef.<clinit>(ClassRef.java:42)

    ... 46 more



    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class       

    oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:262)

        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)

    at PackageInventory.ClassConnectDB.connectdb(ClassConnectDB.java:17)

    at PackageInventory.JFrameBookMaster.jButtonSaveActionPerformed(JFrameBookMaster.java:225)

    at PackageInventory.JFrameBookMaster.access$000(JFrameBookMaster.java:26)

    at PackageInventory.JFrameBookMaster$1.actionPerformed(JFrameBookMaster.java:71)

    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)

    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)

    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)

    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)

    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)

    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)

    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)

    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)

    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)

    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)

    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)

    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)

    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)

    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)

    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)

    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Is it just a warning? does your method run completely?

Comment: Edit your post and remove all those empty lines from your code.

Comment: I don't know the version of ojdbc you use, but the problem seems comes to "java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.internal is sealed"; try with Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");